# two dimensional tail recursion in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, tail-recursion

I am new to **Scala** and started to learn about **tail recursion**. 
I learned that tail recursion in *functional programming* is a counter part of iterations (for loops) in *imperative programming:*

Simple C++ loop to sum list elements:

```
uint32_t sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
    sum += list[i];
}
```

Scala recursive equivalent:

```
def listSum(list: List[Int]): Int = {
  def listSumHelper(list: List[Int], sum: Int): Int = {
    if (list.isEmpty) sum
    else listSumHelper(list.tail, sum + list.head)
  }
  listSumHelper(list, 0)
}
```

**Question:**
What would be a scala recursive equivalent of nested for loops ?

```
uint32_t sum = 0;
for (size_t i = 0; i < list.width(); ++i) {
    for (size_t j = j < list.height(); ++j) {
        sum += list[i][j];
    }
}
```

Comment: The same, except nested. Just like the C++ version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply write an identical list recursion method which works on nested lists (`List[List[Int]]`):

```
def listSum2(list: List[List[Int]]): Int = {
  @tailrec def listSumHelper2(list: List[List[Int]], sum: Int): Int = {
    if (list.isEmpty) sum
    else listSumHelper2(list.tail, sum + listSum(list.head))
  }
  listSumHelper2(list, 0)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want full tail recursion, you should move all your looping into the arguments.  So (here without a helper, just for brevity):

```
def sumsum(xss: List[List[Int]], current: List[Int] = Nil, sum: Int = 0): Int = {
  current match {
    case x :: more => sumsum(xss, more, sum+x)
    case Nil => xss match {
      case xs :: more => sumsum(more, xs, sum)
      case Nil => sum
    }
  }
}
```

But you probably don't need it unless your loops are really short; just have one tail-recursive function call another each iteration.